# What could be the regex for matching 2 different pattern of strings?

Tags: regex

What will be the regex for matching

`a1b2c3` and `a1b2-c3d40-e34ch` both??

** Characters in strings can change

Comment: well, `a1b2-?c3`

Comment: Try `a1b2-?c3.*`

Answer (score 1):

`a1b2(c3|-c3).*`

That should working, too.

If you wanna try on your own I can reccomend: https://regexr.com/6ia3e
The site is preconfigured with my solution.

Comment: no buddy... the charcters may change.. but thanks I got the idea.. `\w(\w|-\w).*`